# How to convert HTML to Atlassian Wiki markup?

Tags: java, maven, html-parsing, renderer

I need to change HTML string to Atlassian Markup String.

I'm trying to do this in Java app (witchout Atlassian SDK).

I found the proper solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37623940/7686437)

But I still have problem:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/opensymphony/util/TextUtils
```

I downloaded additional dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>opensymphony</groupId>
        <artifactId>xwork</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5-atlassian-8</version>
        <systemPath>C:\Users\exo\eclipse-workspace\JiraXMLToCSV\xwork-1.2.5-atlassian-8.jar</systemPath>
        <scope>system</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
        <version>1.10.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.8.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.atlassian.renderer</groupId>
        <artifactId>atlassian-renderer</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.5</version>
        <systemPath>C:\Users\exo\eclipse-workspace\JiraXMLToCSV\atlassian-renderer-8.0.5.jar</systemPath>
        <scope>system</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Should I add some other dependencies?

Comment: OpenSymphony is also available in the Maven Repository, have you tried using the repo resource, instead of a local jar file?
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.opensymphony/xwork/
Or do you need that specific "atlassian" version?

Comment: You are right but this still does not work for me

Answer (score 0):

Add this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.opensymphony</groupId>
    <artifactId>xwork</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.3</version>
</dependency>
```